# jQuery TinyMCE like textbox menu

Tags: jquery, html

So I am looking for a tutorial or guideline how to make a simple text box menu with jQuery (like TinyMCE or the editor here at StackOverflow when u ask a question). I just need something simple to provide two buttons which will on click insert some text into the text box? I really don't know how this is called but I'm sure it's pretty common...

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is a toolbar. You could create your own really easily with jQuery just by using a Div with some images and handling the click event of the image to append the text. Jack's answer should give you a good idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (some of the code is borrowed from Google and modified a bit):

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <input type="button" value="Button 1" id="button1" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 2" id="button2" />
</div>
```

```
$.fn.extend({
    insertAtCaret: function(myValue) {
        this1 = $(this).get(0);
        if (document.selection) {
            this1.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            this1.focus();
        }
        else if (this1.selectionStart || this1.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = this1.selectionStart;
            var endPos = this1.selectionEnd;
            var scrollTop = this1.scrollTop;
            this1.value = this1.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this1.value.substring(endPos, this1.value.length);
            this1.focus();
            this1.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            this1.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            this1.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            this1.value += myValue;
            this1.focus();
        }
    }
});

$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#text1').insertAtCaret('text 1');
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
    $('#text1').insertAtCaret('text 2');
});
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/2TZrh/2/).

Comment: +1 - Great answer and starting point, illustrating my comment above. Alternatively, OP, you can also replace the buttons with images for the more standard "toolbar" look like you find on Stack Overflow or other sites.

Comment: @Delebrin: yeah, as you say, this is only meant as a starting point. The first thing to do with this is change the input types to `image`, add some fancy icons to them, and some CSS to make it nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's append method to add text into a textbox when you click on a button like this:

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {
   $('#textarea_id').append('Add this to the textbox');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Rich Text Editor (RTE). I don't know of any jQuery RTE tutorials, but have a look at the links below for already existing jQuery RTEs:

- [http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editorst](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)
- [http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rtet](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rte)

Comment: Nope I am not looking for a RTE...I am looking for a way to add a toolbar to a text box...that toolbar will not be used to support RTE, I need it for something different...if I needed an RTE would I have said "TinyMCE like" in the title instead of just using TinyMCE XD